# 回答の中に質問者から回答者への返信を書くのはわかりにくい?

Tags: 討議, 質問の仕方

例:

- https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/248/30
- https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/249/30

どちらも、読んでいてちょっと混乱しました。

[image: 回答の中に質問者の返信がある]

この後半部分は、回答者が質問者に返信しているのか?? いや質問者が補足を入れた?? という感じの混乱です。

---

あとから読む立場としては、質問者側の情報は質問に、正解情報は回答にまとまっている方が読みやすいように思います。つまり、補足情報を足すには質問側を編集し:

> **質問:**  
>   こういう問題があります。
>
> 補足: 回答いただいた方法を試してもまだ問題があります。

回答者にコメントで知らせるようにする:

> **回答:**  
>   これでどうでしょうか (回答が違っていた場合は編集で削除してしまう)
>
> コメント欄:  
>     - 試した結果を質問に追記しました。それだと動きません

そして、もしそういうQ&Aを見つけたら、暇があれば編集して整理しておく。

どうでしょう。

Comment: 上記方法に異論はないんですが、信用度が50以上ないと回答にコメント出来ないって仕様のようなので、そこが少し微妙ですね。 http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges

Comment: @tomute 自分の質問・回答や、自分の質問への回答であれば、信用度がなくてもコメントできる ([SEメタのFAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19757/157841)より) はずなので、質問者 <-> 回答者間のやり取りであればコメントを介してできるはず

Comment: そうなんですね。自分の質問に対する回答にコメントしてくださいとあるユーザにお願いしたら、コメント出来ませんと言われたので、てっきりダメかと思ってました。

Comment: 確認の結果、tomuteさんが遭遇したケースは、それと気づかず質問した時とは別のアカウントとしてアクセスしていたためと分かりました。自分の質問についた回答にコメントできない場合は、まずログイン状態やアカウントを確認してみるとよさそうです。

Answer (score 7, accepted):

例として挙げられた回答を読んでみましたが、流れを理解できず3回ほど読み直してしまいました…

編集履歴まで参照すれば質問者−回答者間で会話が行われたと理解できますが、そこまでしないと意図を汲み取れないのはQ&Aサイトとしては適切ではないと思います。

@ento さん提案の通り、質問者−回答者間の会話は「質問内容の追記」「回答内容の追記」で行うのが好ましいと考えます。（本家StackOverflowでもこの方式が主流に感じます）