# 質問は細かく細分化するべき？それとも、得た回答から話を飛躍させても良い？

Tags: 討議, 質問の仕方

> [ボリューム設定が０（ミュート）であっても音を鳴らす方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/6068/%E3%83%9C%E3%83%AA%E3%83%A5%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A0%E3%81%8C%EF%BC%90%E3%81%A7%E3%81%82%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%82%82%E9%9F%B3%E3%82%92%E9%B3%B4%E3%82%89%E3%81%99%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95-swift-%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6)
>   [マナーモードでも音を鳴らすコードをSwiftで実装したい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/6045/%E3%83%9E%E3%83%8A%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A2%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%81%A7%E3%82%82%E9%9F%B3%E3%82%92%E9%B3%B4%E3%82%89%E3%81%99%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89-swift-%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6)

質問が細かく細分化された例だと思います。
マナーモード設定だけについて対処する質問
マナーモードに係わらずボリューム設定が意図的に０（ミュート）になっている時に対処する質問

> [Google Map で現在地を表示する ( GoogleAPIClient )](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/5887/google-map-%E3%81%A7%E7%8F%BE%E5%9C%A8%E5%9C%B0%E3%82%92%E8%A1%A8%E7%A4%BA%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B-googleapiclient)

が追記により目的が達成されるまで追求している例だと思います。
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/posts/5887/revisions
8-12あたりの追記

確実に得たい回答が得られるまで一つの質問内で追求していくのが良いのか
必ずしもベストでない回答を自身で組み立てて目標を達成するのが良いのか
どちらのほうがこのサイトの利用方法として適切ですか？

参考

[回答の中に質問者から回答者への返信を書くのはわかりにくい?](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330/%E5%9B%9E%E7%AD%94%E3%81%AE%E4%B8%AD%E3%81%AB%E8%B3%AA%E5%95%8F%E8%80%85%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E5%9B%9E%E7%AD%94%E8%80%85%E3%81%B8%E3%81%AE%E8%BF%94%E4%BF%A1%E3%82%92%E6%9B%B8%E3%81%8F%E3%81%AE%E3%81%AF%E3%82%8F%E3%81%8B%E3%82%8A%E3%81%AB%E3%81%8F%E3%81%84?rq=1)
[回答後の質問の大幅な変更にはどのようにアクションすべきか](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1558/%E5%9B%9E%E7%AD%94%E5%BE%8C%E3%81%AE%E8%B3%AA%E5%95%8F%E3%81%AE%E5%A4%A7%E5%B9%85%E3%81%AA%E5%A4%89%E6%9B%B4%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AF%E3%81%A9%E3%81%AE%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%AB%E3%82%A2%E3%82%AF%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3%E3%81%99%E3%81%B9%E3%81%8D%E3%81%8B?lq=1)

Answer (score 5):

最終的には「ケースバーケース」という意味では、3100さん回答と同じです。

下記、後々訪れた第三者にとってFAQ的に役立つという観点から、目安としての提案です。

- 当初の質問内容から、対象を具体化したり、**問題自身を詳細化**／**根本原因を深堀り**していくケースでは、「同じ質問投稿への内容追記・改訂」で対応した方が良いと思います。
- 当初の質問内容から、**前提としていた条件**や**別の箇所**が本当の問題と分かったケースでは、「一旦その質問投稿は完結させてしまい、新たな質問投稿として分離する」方が良いと思います。1個目はFAQ的にはあまり意義がありませんが、ノイズが除去された2個目の質問＆回答が役立つという考え方です。

Answer (score 3):

ケースバイケースで、どちらかが適切ではない、というのではないと考えます。

以下、個人の感想です。
適切かどうかはわかりませんが、確実に得たい解答を質問するほうが好きですし、回答者に対しても真意を隠さない分、誠実である気がします。そもそも最初に想定していた方法が間違っている場合も、この方法なら修正が可能です。
もし途中で、さらなる前提知識が必要だということに気づけば、その時点でそこだけ新たな別の質問にするというのはどうでしょうか。