# 質問者と回答者でやり取りしてどんどん内容が長くなっていく投稿にどう対応すれば良い？

Tags: 討議, 質問の仕方, 回答の仕方

質問に1つ回答がついた後、その回答に対する疑問から質問者と回答者の間で議論が起こることが時々あります。

たとえば今回注目した[「ES6でclassとは？」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/33972/es6%E3%81%A7class%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AF)という質問では、[最初の版](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/revisions/33972/1)から現状の[第5版](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/revisions/33972/5)までに4000文字ほど追記が起こっています。これは[Myakuさんの回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/33973/19110)に対する疑問を追記しているためです。Myakuさんも毎回の編集に対して回答を追記しているため、長いQ&Aが生まれています（Myakuさんお疲れ様です＆ありがとうございます）。

そして更に、この質問には現状マイナス4票集まっています。現状質問も回答も第三者から読みにくく、マイナス投票したくなるお気持ちもなんとなく分かるのですが、ではヘルプセンターの[マイナス投票に関する記述](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down)に合致しているのかどうか考えると、微妙な気もします。

今回の質問は、一般にこのようなタイプの質問に対して、どのように対応したらより良いのか、ということです。たとえば以下のことを思いつきました。

- [チャット](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat)を利用する。信用度が100点以上あるユーザーに[チャットルームを作成](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat-rooms)してもらい、そこで議論を続ける。
- 質問を別個に分けて投稿するよう質問者にお願いする。
- (質問の内容次第ですが) [「質問の範囲が広すぎる」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)ことを理由に一旦クローズし、書きなおしてもらった上で再オープンする。

少なくともただマイナス票するだけだと質問者も困惑してしまうのではないかと思います。どうすると良いのでしょう……？

---

2017年4月17日追記: [「ES6でclassとは？」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/33972/es6%E3%81%A7class%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AF)は「質問の範囲が広すぎる」として4月16日にクローズされ、その後同日、同じ質問者によりこの質問の続編[「JSのクラスについて」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/34047/js%E3%81%AE%E3%82%AF%E3%83%A9%E3%82%B9%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6)が投稿されました。

2017年4月23日追記: 類似のメタ投稿があったことを発見しました: [「回答の中に質問者から回答者への返信を書くのはわかりにくい?」](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330/%E5%9B%9E%E7%AD%94%E3%81%AE%E4%B8%AD%E3%81%AB%E8%B3%AA%E5%95%8F%E8%80%85%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E5%9B%9E%E7%AD%94%E8%80%85%E3%81%B8%E3%81%AE%E8%BF%94%E4%BF%A1%E3%82%92%E6%9B%B8%E3%81%8F%E3%81%AE%E3%81%AF%E3%82%8F%E3%81%8B%E3%82%8A%E3%81%AB%E3%81%8F%E3%81%84)

Comment: それなんですよね……私自身も問題に感じているのですが、チャットルームを作成して長い間お付き合いする時間が取れないので結局回答でやり取りしています。回答を分けることも考えたのですが、既存の回答を元に質問が追記されているため、回答に書ききれるまでは記載しようと考えました。

Comment: このメタの発言を見て、慌てて元質問にマイナス投票してきました。もう説明の必要がないくらいひどい状態ですね。「回答」と「質問」を使って単にチャットをしているだけで、私がこちらのサイトを覗くようになってからの1年ちょっとの間だけでも最低最悪のスレッドです。回答者の @Myaku さんは、こちらのサイトでそれなりのご経験があるのですから、ここまで酷くなる前にもう少し考えるべきだったろうと思います。わたし的には今回引用されたスレッドについては(nekketsuuu さんが注記を入れておられる通り、質問の内容次第です)「一旦クローズ」がベストの選択であったろうと感じます。

Comment: @OOPer そうですね。初版でのマイナス票で言葉足らずだったかと思い、確かに考えなしに全レスしていたので気をつけたいと思います。

Comment: @Myaku さん、前向きなご回答ありがとうございます。わたし自身、このような問題提起を見るたびに自分自身はきちんとできているのか反省することしきりです。改めてこのような問題提起をしていただいた nekketsuuu さんに感謝いたします。

Answer (score 5):

> - 質問を別個に分けて投稿するよう質問者にお願いする。
> - (質問の内容次第ですが) 「質問の範囲が広すぎる」ことを理由に一旦クローズし、書きなおしてもらった上で再オープンする。

最初から質問があの内容なのであれば「質問が広すぎる」でよいでしょうが、その状態を招いたのは質問者だけの責任ではありません。そこで「質問が広すぎる」と言われても何が悪かったのかわからないでしょう。クローズ票入れるのであれば、コメントも必須です。マイナス票も同様で、マイナス票**だけ**入れても質問者には何も伝わらないでしょう。

回答者の立場であれば、個人的には、質問→回答→再質問、の時点で打ち切りを考えます。再質問の内容次第ですが、以後別質問にするよう注記付きで回答するかもしれませんし、コメントだけにするかもしれません。見落としてて無反応のものもあるでしょうが、少なくともSO的に好ましくない状態に誘導するようなことはしないよう気をつけています。質問者の大多数はこのような状態が好ましくないとは思ってないでしょうから、これは経験の多い回答者が気を付けてあげないといけない事だと思います。

Answer (score 1):

該当質問で私が回答しておりました。
今の今まで回答していたので言えたことではありませんが、
下記が対応として私もベストだろうと思います。

> - (質問の内容次第ですが) 「質問の範囲が広すぎる」ことを理由に一旦クローズし、書きなおしてもらった上で再オープンする。

参考：[ヘルプセンター＞質問に当たって＞範囲が広すぎる](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)

確かに長くなりそうなら、一度質問文と内容を推敲していただく必要があったかと思います。
こちらお騒がせしました。

また、該当質問に関しましてクローズまで残り一票なので私の一票で一旦クローズさせていただきました。
質問者様へはコメントにて一度質問を纏めていただけないか打診いたしました。
以後、気をつけてみたいと思います。

Answer (score 1):

回答への質問は回答へのコメントで行ってもらうように誘導し、もしコメントの応酬が長続きするようならそのままチャットへ移行するのが良いかもしれません。コメントじゃ短くて書ききれないということであれば、元々の質問の範囲が広すぎたということで、分からなくなった点ごとに質問して頂くというのはどうでしょうか。

そもそも回答への返信を質問本文で行うと全体を理解するのにページを上下させねばならず可読性が落ちるため避けるべきで、となると現状コメント機能を活用するしかないのではないかと思いました。